# Browser loads every JS file in "source" folder

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, google-chrome-devtools

I am using a Foundation-based wordpress theme: FoundationPress.

Just can't understand what caused this:

JS codes are set to be loaded conditionally in functions.php but today every of them is loaded by every page in a folder called "source", which only existed in Chrome's Dev tool window.

Some of the errors might come from duplicate variables or functions.

If I edited the same filename from which it actually located, nothing changed.

How do I fix them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

javascript file to assets folder

## See = [Github FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/tree/master/assets/javascript/custom)

**If the problem continues to re-install.**

Comment: Yes, I put every js and css in assets/ folder. 
Just re-install and Chrome doesn't load /source/ folder again.